# awk match / compare / 2 columns for in each file (for 2 files)

Tags: join, awk, compare, match, multiple-columns

after several multiple findings here on forum i am still stucking to print my desired output for 2 files

where i would like to match file1 with file2 and combine them together into 1 file based on 1st column and 2nd column in each file.
(rows in both files are not sorted); column no.5 in file1 and column no.3 in file2 is not a key for matching ( but if its mandatory it can be used as an option too)

not sure if best way is to do it in loop thru awk from 2 diff. folders where in one folder are files named SITEA; SITEB; SITEC etc.. with FILENAME info from file1 and same files named in 2nd folder with FILENAME info containg like from file2 .

Not sure if its possible to add there if there is mismatch containg in each of file to print word EMPTY and add it to desired output file.

**file1**

```
SITEA 222 dummy dummy x8a7sdf dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x683 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x69b dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x69d dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEC 200 dummy dummy x11xdc1 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x6bc dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x305 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x323 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x693 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x300 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x680 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x688 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 151 dummy dummy x87f777 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x68c dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x33b dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf37 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x68e dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x694 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x6a5 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITED 200 dummy dummy x11xdc0 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf36 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xffd dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x306 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x307 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x325 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x686 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x680 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x33c dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x6be dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x6ba dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xffe dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x33e dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf00 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x696 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf1c dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf1e dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x69a dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf34 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf35 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xfff dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x681 dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x33d dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x33d dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 100 dummy dummy x11x33d dummyvalues dummyvalues
```

**file2**

```
SITEA 357 x11x683 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 x11x33b dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 x11x693 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 x11x680 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 x11x69b dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 x11x686 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 x11x6a5 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 x11x69d dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 x11xffd dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 x11x6ba dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 x11x680 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 x11xf1c dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 x11x68e dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 x11x69a dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 x11x681 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 x11x33c dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 x11x694 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 x11x696 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEC 200 x11xdc1 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 x11x6bc dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 x11xf37 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 x11x325 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITED 200 x11xdc0 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 x11xf00 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 x11xf36 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 x11x6be dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 x11x33d dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 x11x305 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 x11x688 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 x11x33e dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 x11xffe dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 x11x300 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 x11xfff dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 x11xf1e dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 x11x306 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 x11x307 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 x11xf35 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 x11x68c dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 x11xf34 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 x11x323 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 45 a8d7f99 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 008 8sd7f77 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
```

**desired output:**

```
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x683 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 357 x11x683 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x69b dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 357 x11x69b dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x69d dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 357 x11x69d dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEC 200 dummy dummy x11xdc1 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEC 200 x11xdc1 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x6bc dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 357 x11x6bc dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x305 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 200 x11x305 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x323 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 200 x11x323 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x693 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 357 x11x693 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x300 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 200 x11x300 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x680 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 357 x11x680 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x688 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 357 x11x688 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x68c dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 357 x11x68c dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x33b dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 200 x11x33b dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf37 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 200 x11xf37 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x68e dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 357 x11x68e dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x694 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 357 x11x694 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x6a5 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 357 x11x6a5 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITED 200 dummy dummy x11xdc0 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITED 200 x11xdc0 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf36 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 200 x11xf36 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xffd dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 200 x11xffd dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x306 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 200 x11x306 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x307 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 200 x11x307 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x325 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 200 x11x325 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x686 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 357 x11x686 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x680 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 357 x11x680 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x33c dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 200 x11x33c dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x6be dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 357 x11x6be dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x6ba dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 357 x11x6ba dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xffe dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 200 x11xffe dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x33e dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 200 x11x33e dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf00 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 200 x11xf00 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x696 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 357 x11x696 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf1c dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 200 x11xf1c dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf1e dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 200 x11xf1e dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 357 dummy dummy x11x69a dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 357 x11x69a dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf34 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 200 x11xf34 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xf35 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 200 x11xf35 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEB 200 dummy dummy x11xfff dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEB 200 x11xfff dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 357 dummy dummy x11x681 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 357 x11x681 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x33d dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 200 x11x33d dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY SITEB 45 a8d7f99 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY SITEB 008 8sd7f77 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 151 dummy dummy x87f777 dummyvalues dummyvalues EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY
SITEA 222 dummy dummy x8a7sdf dummyvalues dummyvalues EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY
SITEA 200 dummy dummy x11x33d dummyvalues dummyvalues  EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY
SITEA 100 dummy dummy x11x33d dummyvalues dummyvalues  EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY
```

Thank you

i got it partially worked with this code only in case if i will interchange columns in file1 and will put column no5 next to column no3

```
awk 'NR==FNR{
  if(FNR==1){print}
  a[$1 $2 $3]=$0
  next
}
a[$1 $2 $3]!=$0 && a[$1 $2 $3]!=""{
  print a[$1 $2 $3],$0
}'
```

but it not showing non matching lines as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1,$2,$5]=$0; next}
             {if(($1,$2,$3) in a) 
                {print a[$1,$2,$3],$0; delete a[$1,$2,$3]}
              else print "EMPTY",$0} 
     END     {for(k in a) print a[k], "EMPTY"} file1 file2
```

First file has $5 part of the key, use that while storing the values.

if you know the number of fields in both files, add the correct number of "EMPTY" fillers, otherwise you can code that as well.  Here I omitted for simplicity.

file2 will dictate the order of the output.  For entries in file1, but missing in file2 the order will not be preserved, need extra logic if required.

Comment: hi @karakfa, after week delay, i managed this like that 

`SITEA 222 x8a7sdf dummy dummy dummyvalues dummyvalues
SITEA 200 x11x323 dummy dummy dummyvalues dummyvalues SITEA 200 x11x323 dummyvalues dummyvalues dummyvalues`


`awk 'NR==FNR{if(FNR==1){print} a[$1 $2 $3]=$0 ;next} a[$1 $2 $3]!=$0 && a[$1 $2 $3]~!""{print a[$1 $2 $3],$0}' filea fileb`

but missing to have this part of printed output


`SITEA 151 dummy dummy x87f777 dummyvalues dummyvalues EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY`

will try reuse part of your code and some other sources and will post it here result

Comment: my bad @karakfa, after rerun it works like a charm,
your works better +1

with added multiple EMPTY blocks  based on need its works like a charm e.g.

`awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1,$2,$5]=$0; next}
             {if(($1,$2,$3) in a)
                {print a[$1,$2,$3],$0; delete a[$1,$2,$3]}
              else print "EMPTY","EMPTY", $0}
     END     {for(k in a) print a[k], "EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY"}'  filea fileb`

overlooked yours part for $5th column